# Merging diferent vectors into a 0/1 dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have three vectors containing names:

```
one  <- c("a","b","d","f") 
two  <- c("b", "e")
three<- c("a", "b", "c", "f")
```

I want to join them in a dataframe (or matrix) where rows are the names, columns are the vectors and values are 1 or 0 is the name is present in the vector.
Is there a way to do it in R?

My expected results should be a dataframe like so:

```
  one two three
a 1   0   1
b 1   1   1
c 0   0   1
d 1   0   0
e 0   1   0
f 1   0   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of the vectors and then use the `sapply` shown.  No packages are used.

```
L <- list(one = one, two = two, three = three)

rnames <- sort(unique(unlist(L)))
m <- +sapply(L, function(x) rnames %in% x)
rownames(m) <- rnames

m
```

giving:

```
  one two three
a   1   0     1
b   1   1     1
c   0   0     1
d   1   0     0
e   0   1     0
f   1   0     1
```

### Variations

The `sapply` line above could be written even more compactly like this:

```
m <- +sapply(L, `%in%`, x = rnames)
```

or we could use `outer`. This also sets the row names:

```
m <- + outer(setNames(rnames, rnames), L, Vectorize(`%in%`))
```

Comment: In there a way to retain the index?

Comment: Have added rownames.

Comment: What does `+sapply` do?

Comment: It converts the result of the sapply from TRUE/FALSE elements to 1/0's.

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` approach could be to construct a list of three objects, bring them into one dataframe, `unnest` the values and get the data in wide format using `pivot_wider`.

```
library(tidyverse)

lst(one, two, three) %>%
   enframe() %>%
   unnest(cols = "value") %>%
   mutate(n = 1) %>%
   #spread(name, n, fill = 0) %>% #in earlier version of tidyr
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, 
              values_from = n, 
              values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
   arrange(value)

#  value   one   two three
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         1     0     1
#2 b         1     1     1
#3 c         0     0     1
#4 d         1     0     0
#5 e         0     1     0
#6 f         1     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `table` and `stack` from `base R`

```
table(stack(mget(c('one', 'two', 'three'))))
#    ind
#values one two three
#     a   1   0     1
#     b   1   1     1
#     c   0   0     1
#     d   1   0     0
#     e   0   1     0
#     f   1   0     1
```

---

Or using `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(mget(c("one", "two", "three"))))
```